# Q: WPF - To what extent should Resource Dictionaries be avoided?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

I've heard a few times that Resource Dictionaries can slowly but surely build up and become drag on the performance of an app (especially as merged dictionaries begin to reference other merged dictionaries and it all clumps together into an unintended matrix of resources).

With this in mind, should styles be assimilated into c# as custom controls that intelligently try to carry out what the style(s) were going to set the properties of a given control to, set by an internally defined Enum="Example" instead of Style="{StaticResource Example}"?
And if so, at what point/level of ResourceDictionary 'severity' *(for lack of a better word)* should this be done?

Additionally, how much attention should XAML even be given over C# if it turns out C# is more efficient at runtime?
Should XAML simply be used as an area to place minimalistic tags ultimately defined, styled, given properties and controlled by C#?

Comment: [Citation needed](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/citation-needed).

Comment: Possibly [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion and experience, I would say resources are a very good tool provided by WPF engine. Now, question is performance issues, to answer that question I would point two huge tools Visual Studio and Blend both are build in WPF and UI elements are using dynamic resources heavily. But, there is no performance issues with the tool. So, to correctly answer your question, you should be using the correct technology at correct place. Resources provide you a great flexibility when you want to modify some thing like theme or visual appearance. Although to your point you need to be very careful of the usage and try to keep resources in check. Include only required resources in your page.

So, conclusion:
1. No, do not make a practice of converting everything into control and not use resources at all.
2. Yes, you need to make a considered effort in respect of resources to keep application performance optimized.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to memory bloat due to repeatedly adding the same resources via transitive dependencies, check out the various implementations of `SharedResourceDictionary` floating about on the web. This can reduce working set and reduce startup time (in my experience) but you should take care to avoid memory leaks as most just store a static map from URI string to `ResourceDictionary`.

If you're making a more general question about whether resource dictionaries are useful or not, then yes, they are very useful and even essential for many kinds of common XAML patterns (such as `StaticResource`).